# SFDC Flow Launched from Custom Button

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, visual-flows

I have a custom button on the Opportunity object that launches a Visualforce page.  The Visualforce page passes the Opportunity ID to the Flow then launches it and sets the finish location.  I know my Flow works properly because I have tested it outside the button and it works as expected.  When I run the button I get the error below and I don't think the Opportunity Id is being passed to the Flow.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity" extensions="NewQuoteController">
  <flow:interview name="Create_New_Quote" interview="{!NewQuoteFlow}" finishLocation="{!Finish}">
      <apex:param name="OppId" value="{!Opportunity.Id}"/>
  </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class NewQuoteController{

    public NewQuoteController(ApexPages.StandardController myController){}

  public Flow.Interview.Create_New_Quote NewQuoteFlow {get;set;}

  public PageReference Finish {
    get {
      PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + NewQuote_Id);
      pageRef.setRedirect(true);
      return pageRef;
    }
    set { Finish = value; }
  }

  public String NewQuote_Id {
    get {
      String strTemp = '';

      if(NewQuoteFlow != null) {
        strTemp = string.valueOf(NewQuoteFlow.getVariableValue('NewQuoteId'));
      }
      return strTemp;
    }

  set { NewQuote_Id = value; }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you captured a debug log?  Is the error occurring in your Apex or in your Flow?

Comment: Nothing appears in my debug log as an error.  I've added the error message I am getting to the original post.  When I run the Flow from a button with "/Flow/Create_New_Qote?OppId={!Opportunity.Id}" it works as expected.  The problem must be with the VF page and/or Controller, I assume.

Comment: I'm confused - your first paragraph says you're getting a dereference null object, but your screenshot is something else.  Are you getting two errors or just one?

Comment: I was getting 2, but I fixed the null error.  Sorry for the confusion.  I've edited the post